# Failed audit by commenting on it

Tags: bug, review-audits

I was given https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/8973480 as an audit to 'first question' asked by a user. I wrote a (rather lengthy) comment that the question could be structured better by first stating the topic and the intent or question in words and asking how the follow-up conditions relate to it, and then giving the well-worded example(s) as they are. Then clicked "I'm done" - however I failed the audit - why? I stand by my asessment that the structure of the question is not ideal - despite it being a good question with all necessary information.

As such I'm not sure it's a good audit question.